# Short Story where school kid (and their family) turn out to be alien(s)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think this was from a book or collection of short stories, but it may have been standalone. IIRC the text was pretty big and I read this as a child, so most likely it was aimed at YA or younger. I'm in the UK and so the book was at least printed here - unsure if there was any wording which would have indicated a British or US author.

**All I remember is the twist**: Written in the first person, a school kid discovers that their entire family are aliens when the family hold an intervention in their kitchen.

It turns our protagonist is *also* an alien - the intervention is to explain to them that the aliens are on a kind of school trip to Earth, and that some (alien) children can get so caught up in their experiences they forget what they really are.

I think they went back to space and had to leave their new human best friend behind!

Comment: Could it have been The Dark Side of Nowhere by Neal Shusterman? The protagonist is the son of aliens, but they were the vanguard of an invasion force, not on a school trip. They also have a talk about their past, I believe.

Comment: @user109599 Post this as an answer! Having read a summary this sounds like it must be it, but I don't remember the ending at all. Is it possible a short story collection included only a small part of the full book?

Comment: I don't believe it was ever part of a short story collection. I'll post it ad an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it The Dark Side of Nowhere by Neal Shusterman?  Here's a summary of the scene you remember: Jason goes home to confront his parents about the glove. At this, his dad finally tells Jason the truth: Jason and his family are aliens. They take on the form of students and parents who leave town. Moreover, the monthly shots are designed to hide the aliens’ true appearances.